# Calling main activity from non-activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been trying many different ways and getting null pointer exceptions.

Scenario: Activity1 loads on start and calls Activity2 if the num of rows in the table is 0. Now I want it to go back to Activity1 when the number of rows is 0 and that call would coem from the db handler.
In the database handler class:

```
    if(num ==0){
        Activity1 bs1 = new Activity1();
        Context context = bs1.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent();//
        intent.setClass(context, Activity1.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Activity1 onCreate()

```
    int num = db.numOfRows();
    if(num==0){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } else {    
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));//
    }
```

Activity2 onCreate()

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.moreprojects);
        populateRows();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DNRN, afaics, context. bs1 does not have an application context at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont use constructor to call new activity. See below:

```
Context context = bs1.getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //required to launch from non-activity
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's throwing a null pointer at Context context = bs1.getApplicationContext();

Comment: so it means your **bs1** is *null*. Fix this first, and then hope it will work

Comment: That's what I don't quite understand. Here's the scenario that I forgot to mention. I have two activities and one non-activity class. We'll call them Activity1 and 2 respectively. Activity 2 loads and needs to call Activity 1 when there are no rows in table. The call would come in from the non-activity class to load Activity 1.

Comment: show your code where your activity is engaged with non-activity. just include it in your question and msg me here

Comment: Again, this is wrong `Activity1 bs1 = new Activity1();`. Show me your full code for both classes

Comment: The relevant code is there. Or at least I hope. Given the Activity2 call is coming from Activity1.. is there an easy way to just go back to it once the rows are 0?

Comment: Populate rows just calls the database and inserts tablerows into the view. Any idea why a null is being called?

Comment: but you are also trying to launch new activity inside populateRows(). rite? so i need to see what could be wrong in it

Comment: No I'm not actually. That's in Activity2 and loads properly. The null is called once the rows are empty which resides in the first code snippet (db handler). When the rows are empty it should bring up Activity1 but it fails at the Context code.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't instantiate the Activity class yourself. Try to start it this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both. Unfortunately the issue is with attaining the context variable. In his code a null pointer is thrown at Context context = bs1.getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an activity from a context that is not already an activity. In your case, there is not solution. You may want to consider sending a notification with a PendingIntent to start your activity *if the user wants to*